# Subset dataframe based of non-sequential dates

Tags: r, date, conditional-statements, subset, plyr

I have data that looks like this

```
df<-data.frame(datecol=as.Date(c("2010-04-03","2010-04-04","2010-04-05","2010-04-06","2010-04-07",
                                    "2010-04-03","2010-04-04","2010-04-05","2010-04-06","2010-04-07",
                                    "2010-05-06","2010-05-07","2010-05-09","2010-06-06","2010-06-07")),x=c(1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1),type=c(rep("A",5),rep("B",5),rep("C",5)))

> df
      datecol x type
1  2010-04-03 1    A
2  2010-04-04 1    A
3  2010-04-05 1    A
4  2010-04-06 0    A
5  2010-04-07 1    A
6  2010-04-03 1    B
7  2010-04-04 1    B
8  2010-04-05 0    B
9  2010-04-06 0    B
10 2010-04-07 0    B
11 2010-05-06 1    C
12 2010-05-07 0    C
13 2010-05-09 0    C
14 2010-06-06 0    C
15 2010-06-07 1    C
```

I need to subset this dataframe by type, where I only keep the "types" which have 2 or more different dates and those dates are at least 1 day apart. In the above example type A has 4 different dates, and type C has 2 different dates which are more than 1 day apart, so I want to save these two as a new dataframe. Type B has 2 different dates, but they are not 1 day apart, so I don't want to keep it.

I was thinking to do it in a loop count how many unique date are within each type, leave everything which has more than 2 different dates. Then I would look at the ones which have only 2 different dates and calculate the distance between them and leave only the ones where distance is more than 1. But it seems that there should be a more efficient way. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution with `data.table`:

```
#make sure datecol is Date
df$datecol <- as.Date(df$datecol)

library(data.table)
#x needs to be 1 and the date difference more than a day per type
#then in the second [] we select the TRUEs
setDT(df)[x == 1, diff(datecol) > 1, by = type][V1 == TRUE, type]
#[1] A C
#Levels: A B C
```